# PHP cannot upload multiple images

Tags: php, image, upload

I have a form in which I want to upload at most five images. The name and extension of the images are supposed to be inserted in the database table 'images' and then uploaded to the _uploads/name_of_the_album/ directory.

The problem is, when I choose some images and hit upload, only the first image is uploaded correctly, the other images fail.

Here is my code:

```
if(isset($_FILES['image']) === true){
    $files = $_FILES['image'];

    $allowed_ext = array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'gif');

    $album_id = (int)$_GET['album_id'];
    $album_name = $_GET['album_name'];

    for($i=0; $i<count($files['name']); $i++){
        $name = $files['name'][$i];
        $tmp_name = $files['tmp_name'][$i];
        $size = $files['size'][$i];

        $ext = explode('.', $files['name'][$i]);
        $ext = strtolower(end($ext));

        $img_name = explode('.', $files['name'][$i]);
        $img_name = strtolower(current($img_name));

                    //do some testing echos to see the result
        //echo $img_name."<br>";

                     //here i'm going to add some validation as soon as
                     // i fix the multi-upload problem

        //insert image into database
        $query_insert_image = "INSERT INTO `images` (album_id, image_name, image_ext) VALUES ({$album_id}, '{$img_name}', '{$ext}') ";
        $insert_image = mysql_query($query_insert_image, $connection) or die(mysql_error());

        if(mysql_affected_rows() == 1){

            move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, '../_uploads/'.$album_name.'/'.$name);
        }

        //redirect
        redirect_to("view_album.php?succeed=1");
    }//end the for loop

    //echo '<pre>',print_r($files, true),'</pre>';
}
```

And here is some of the code of the form:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formUploadImages" id="formUploadImages">
    <p>
        <label for="image">Choose one or more Image(s):</label><br />
        <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" /><br />
        <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" /><br />
        <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" /><br />
        <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" /><br />
        <input type="file" name="image[]" id="image" />
    </p>
......
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: only the first image inserted in database and uploaded in the directory, the others i choose don't do that

Comment: Side-note, never use the same ID multiple times in an HTML document. Use a class instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you're cutting the branch from under your own feet.

```
redirect_to("view_album.php?succeed=1");
```

Redirecting means refreshing the page which means the end of execution. When that redirect is triggered after the first `for` loop ends and first image is uploaded the `for` will not continue to the next iteration.

And the fix of course is to push that line after the for loop (and never expect anything after a redirect to ever execute - unless the headers are already sent).

Most functions that do what `redirect_to()` does (it's not a core function it's based on another function `header()`) also make sure execution stops (have a line calling `header()` and another line calling `die()`/`exit()`).

Comment: THANKS A LOT!!!!! you 're absolutely right!!! I put the function after the for loop and it worked absolutely fine!!!

Answer (score 1):

try this php code ,working for me:

```
for($i=1;$i<6;$i++)
{
if(!empty($_FILES['image_upload'.$i])):
$target = "images/".$_FILES['image_upload'.$i]['name'];
$image_upload.= ",".mysql_real_escape_string(($_FILES['image_upload'.$i]['name']));
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image_upload'.$i]['tmp_name'], $target);
endif;
}
```

create a folder in your root named "images" ,all the images will be moved in this folder.
html form may be looks like:

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="formUploadImages" id="formUploadImages">
<p>
    <label for="image">Choose one or more Image(s):</label><br />
    <input type="file" name="image_upload1" id="image_upload1" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="image_upload2" id="image_upload2" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="image_upload3" id="image_upload3" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="image_upload4" id="image_upload4" /><br />
    <input type="file" name="image_upload5" id="image_upload5" />
</p>
```

......

this code is running on my end ,and after some editing as according to your needs may be useful for you.
Happy coding!

Comment: thanks for the reply! I've already fixed it. Just a question. How can i validate on image's dimentions?? for eg check that the image has width more than 150px and height more than 100px

Comment: what type of validation? you want to make that only more than 150x100 images are allowed to save in database otherwise not? images type validation and size(in memory)validation is easy.

Comment: if you want to use size validation on dimension try getimagesize() method of php. see http://php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesize.php .hope it help:)

Answer (score 0):

foreach($_POST['image'] as $report_id){
             $sql="INSERT INTO `images` (album_id, image_name, image_ext) VALUES ('{$album_id}', '{$report_id}', '{$ext}') ";
             $queryExe=mysql_query($sql);
       }

replace this code in the place of your code after "//insert image into database" .

Comment: If the ID is numeric there is no need to quote it. Also what are you correcting exactly? I can't tell the difference between the two snippets of code except for the quoted $album_id.

Answer (score 0):

http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.multiple.php

Read the Warning block 'Since PHP 5.2.12, the max_file_uploads configuration...'. Maybe that's the problem.

And there are some good examples and maybe You should use foreach instead of for.

Comment: Why should he use `foreach` instead of `for`? `foreach` iterates over arrays and objects using their `current()`/`next()` methods while `for` is much simpler it just compares and increments.

Comment: That's just a private opinion. Foreach is cleaner and the code is more simple. Easier to debug. Iterating arrays, that's why it created for. But again, that's my opinion.

Comment: It was not created for cleaner code, it was created to allow iteration over non-numerically indexed arrays (Dictionaries, HashMaps et.al.). If it's not numerically indexed you wouldn't be able to use a `for` loop. And in C/C++ there is no `foreach` loop, you can however use a `while` instead and it's pretty clean.

Comment: But that's water under the bridge. I haven't noticed that `redirect_to("view_album.php?succeed=1");` thingy.

Answer (score 0):

1) Create a .htaccess file in the root folder of web server.

2) Put the following code in side the .htaccess file and save it.

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 20M
php_value post_max_size 20M
php_value max_execution_time 200
php_value max_input_time 200
```

Now you can upload the file-size up-to 20MB in a simple way using file field in your html form and move_uploaded_file() function available in PHP.